# How to create address independent code for STM32F746?

Tags: gcc, stm32f7

I need to create an address independent, dynamically reallocable code for STM32F746: a code (program) that I will store in one place (i.e. external Flash), than load it into the RAM (internal or external SDRAM) to some other (always different) address and run it. Basically, all internal program calls should be relative calls and relative jumps instead of traditional, absolute calls and jumps. The code will be loaded from th Flash to the RAM by the "code loader" that will run in the background - the part I have already resolved. Someone knows how to set GCC to create this kind of code? I am using Eclispe STM32 as a development IDE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024387/trying-to-load-position-independent-code-on-cortex-m3

Comment: Have you tried `gcc -fpic?